# DefaultCellStyle.Backcolor gives me wrong color in DataGridView in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a Datagridview and would like to change the color of the Rows like this: All the Rows that have the same value in the first Column should have the same color.
I made this to Achieve this:

```
    private void AlternatingRows()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView_daten.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Index > 0)
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Substring(0, 5) == dataGridView_daten.Rows[row.Index - 1].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Substring(0, 5))
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = dataGridView_daten.Rows[row.Index - 1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor;
                }
                else if (dataGridView_daten.Rows[row.Index - 1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.AliceBlue)
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(226, 241, 254);
                }
                else if (dataGridView_daten.Rows[row.Index - 1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(226, 241, 254))
                {
                    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

So basically if the value of the first cell is the same as in the row above, the color should be the same... I call this method after I bound the Data to the DataGridView...  I also tried to call it in the `CellFormatting` Event, but it did not work. 
My Problem is that the Rows still have all the same color. When I debug it, `DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` is empty... Why does the `DefaultCellStyle.BackColor` return Empty?
Like that the `If` clause `else if (dataGridView_daten.Rows[row.Index -1].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor == Color.FromArgb(226, 241, 254))`
 will never be true...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it with a `color` that changes when the number changes:

```
    private void AlternatingRows()
    {
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView_daten.Rows)
        {
            if (row.Index > 0)
            {
                if (row.Cells[0].Value.ToString().Substring(0, 5) != dataGridView_daten.Rows[row.Index - 1].Cells[0].Value.ToString().Substring(0, 5))
                {
                    if (Farbe == Color.FromArgb(226, 241, 254))
                        Farbe = Color.AliceBlue;
                    else
                        Farbe = Color.FromArgb(226, 241, 254);
                }
                row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Farbe;
            }
        }
    }
```